# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager UI Frozen with Swift

Tags: asynchronous, afnetworking, swift

I have one question, I'm doing a short example with AFNetworking and Swift and I'm seeing that my UI is frozen while data is being dowloaded.. is it normal?

This is my code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var manager:AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func getJSON(sender : AnyObject) {
        manager.GET("https://itunes.apple.com/es/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=10/json", parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON:  \(responseObject.description)")
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error:  \(error.localizedDescription)")
            })
    }

}
```

Comment: I've never used `AFNetworking` before. Are those methods normally synchronous, or asynchronous?

Comment: I'd be a little concerned about using a local variable for the operation manager. Can you convert that to an instance variable of your ViewController class and try it that way?

Comment: If I convert the local variable it into instance variable I get the same behavior. It's strange

Comment: @CraigOtis Those methods are asynchronous (and the completion blocks are called on the main thread.)

Comment: Can you pause the app in the debugger to determine what your main thread is doing while it's waiting for the download?

Comment: You mean that  all thing I do in succes or failure block are executed in the main thread? then that is my error!! 
If I want to refresh an UITableView  asynchronously when succes is called, how can I do that?